# Flat view of Pivot

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, max, pivot-table

I have an Excel file that looks like the attached screenshot. I need to create another spreadsheet where I only need the rows for the latest available year. For example, I need rows #6 & 7 for `ABC Inc`, row #27 for `Karen Engineering` and row #32 for `Hartford`.

I tried a PivotTable with Max of Year but it's not a flat view and I cannot bring in all the columns. What else can I try or how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relying on the sorting, a column containing `=IF(AND(A1=A2,C1<C2),"","*")` copied down should enable you to use Filter to copy the required rows.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the your help. I can either use filter or copy-paste the formula as value and sort and delete all the rows without *. Thanks so much.

Comment: I have one more issues. sometimes some of the rows have same year repeating multiple times since they have multiple license files. How would I take care of that?

Comment: actually the sample data I posted did not have the scenario where they have 2 files for the same year. so I have 2 or 3 rows of same year. I need to keep all the file from recent years. for example, Hartford LLC may have 2 license files in 2008 so there are 2 rows. For Hartford LLC may have 2 license files for 2014 so there are 2 rows for the 2014. In this case I need to ignore 2008 and keep all the rows for 2014. May be a Max formula for the year and some formula for column B. I am not sure. I would truly appreciate your help.

Comment: =IF(AND(A2=A3,C2<=C3),"","*") works and it tags the latest year. but say in the latest year I have 2 license files then I need both rows to be tagged. If you want I can provide print shots. I updated the original post with a better print shots of the excel workbook. In this scenario I need to keep row 6 and 7 belongs to ABC Inc. and row 21 and 22 belonging to mom-pop company.

Comment: I was trying this formula =IF(AND((A2=A3,C2<=C3),AND(B2<>B3),""),"","*") but it gives me #value! error.

Comment: Looks like this formula =IF(AND(A2=A3,C2<=C3, B2<>B3),"","*") would work but it's only tagging the 1 row instead of multiple rows. =IF(AND(A3=A4,C3<>C4, B3<>B4),"","*") almost works but it tagging multiple years for the same company.

Comment: =IF(OR(AND(A1=A2,C1<C2),A1=A3),"","*")  worked. Thank you so much.